# JBWEB004052: Exception occurred when flushing data

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I had this running on tomcat using just notepad to edit but I can not get it to run in eclipse deploying to wildfly. Please help!

This is the error kind of long:

```
18:26:23,509 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-100) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ADTF_WebProj/BasicAjax/Basic.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB004052: Exception occurred when flushing data
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB004052: Exception occurred when flushing data
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:182) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:633) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB004052: Exception occurred when flushing data
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:194) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:115) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:74) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.BasicAjax.Basic_jsp._jspService(Basic_jsp.java:122)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:229) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:159) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JBWEB004226: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:190) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:116) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:191) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    ... 51 more
```

I am pretty sure the error is in the following code in basic.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/xml"%><%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%

response.addHeader("Cache-Control","max-age=1, must-revalidate");

// --- Database connection ---
String Path = request.getServletPath().replaceAll("[^\\/\\\\]*$",""); // Relative path to script directory ending with "/"
java.sql.Connection Conn = null;
java.sql.Statement Cmd = null;
try {
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
   Conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:<url>:<port>:<sid>", "<username>", "<password>");
      Cmd = Conn.createStatement();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   out.print("Error is:" + e);
   out.close();
   throw new Exception("");
   }

try {
   StringBuffer S = new StringBuffer();
   S=null;
   java.sql.ResultSet R = Cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM GRIDDATA WHERE GRIDID = 11");

   S.append("<Grid><Body><B>");
   while(R.next()){     
     S.append("<I, GRIDID='" + R.getString(1) + "'"
            + " id='" + R.getString(2) + "'"
            + " DRAWING='" + R.getString(3) + "'"
            + " TITLE='" + R.getString(4) + "'"
            + "/>");
     }
   S.append("</B></Body></Grid>");
   out.print(S.toString());
   R.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
   out.print("Error in getting data !<br>");
   out.print(ex.getMessage());
   }
%>
```

Comment: This error was caused because I was missing a jdbc library actually I had it in the wrong sub directory.  Thanks to those that looked at the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused because I was missing a jdbc library actually I had it in the wrong sub directory. Thanks to those that looked at the issue.